# Selenium java code to click a disabled tab in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: java, selenium

I am a tester and recently started to automate site testing using selenium. So forgive me if my question is not up to the mark or irrelevant or repetitive.

[Snippet of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGa7s.png)

As in the attachment you can see when the "Overview" tab is enabled the rest two tabs are disabled i.e. "Yesterday" and "Statistics". As the page loads the "overview" tab is enabled and the contents are displayed. But i need to click the "Statistics" tab when the page loads.

I tried the below codes but it didn't work. Can anyone kindly help me on this, i would be really thankful.

Code tried :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Statistics']")).click();
```

and

```
WebDriverWait wait0 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
WebElement ElementBtn0 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='WD48']"));
wait0.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ElementBtn0));
ElementBtn0.click();
```

trace log :

```
1511342545379   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1511342545433   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:10000
1511342546659   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\abcd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.8ZsWdwktZ3Ao"
1511342549254   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
[Child 18796, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 18796, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1511342554313   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2000
1511342554659   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1511342554829   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 4294967297
Nov 22, 2017 2:52:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1511342555319   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "beforeunload" for "about:blank"
1511342556041   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pagehide" for "about:blank"
1511342556042   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "unload" for "about:blank"
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/example line 60: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/example line 63: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/exampleclasses.js?D5153EE28C47, line 95: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/exampleclasses.js?D5153EE28C47, line 314: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/exampleclasses.js?D5153EE28C47, line 314: unreachable code after return statement
1511342561264   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "DOMContentLoaded" for https://www.example.com:12345/example "
1511342561957   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pageshow" for "https://www.example.com:12345/example "
1511342563281   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "beforeunload" for "https://www.example.com:12345/example "
1511342563789   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pagehide" for "https://www.example.com:12345/example "
1511342563814   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "unload" for "https://www.example.com:12345/example "
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/example line 60: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/example line 63: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/exampleclasses.js?D5153EE28C47, line 95: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/exampleclasses.js?D5153EE28C47, line 314: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.example.com:12345/exampleclasses.js?D5153EE28C47, line 314: unreachable code after return statement
1511342565476   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "DOMContentLoaded" for "https://www.example.com:12345/example "
1511342565703   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pageshow" for "https://www.example.com:12345/example "
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //a[@title='Statistics']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.8ZsWdwktZ3Ao, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=XP, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=57.0, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=4204, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, moz:webdriverClick=false}]
Session ID: dac831b2-d5ac-4700-b222-5c7a6e5fab82
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[@title='Statitics']}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:458)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at messagemonitor.Forefox.main(Forefox.java:69)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @4M01 no, i am not getting any error but its not navigating to the "Statics" tab :( once the page is loaded

Comment: That is strange, it means the code you have written to get element does its job. Often it happens Relative XPath can retrieve another element. Are you sure that your XPath finds single an elemnet in Page?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML?

Comment: @4M01 as per my understanding i feel as soon as the page loads the "Overview" tab and its contents are enabled where as the tabs "Yesterday" and "Statistics" are disabled. When you click manually the tabs "Yesterday" and "Statistics" it can be accessed but via selenium its not able to click the disabled tabs. I hope i am making my point clear

Comment: if you are sure about that, you can click using javascript :- `JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ElementBtn0);`

Answer (score 0):

may be, you can try with actions class as given below.

```
WebElement tabStatistics=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Statistics']"));
Actions actions=new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(tabStatistics).click(tabStatistics).perform();
```

It may works.

Comment: i got error as below :

Session ID: dac831b2-d5ac-4700-b222-5c7a6e5fab82
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[@title='Statistics']}
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: can you give me full stack trace info?. Please check the xpath is referring the correct element.

Comment: added the trace log in the query above

Comment: It is nosuchelement exception, so the element is not appear on the page, may be you need to wait some times before click on it. add wait statement and try again.

Comment: i tried adding wait but its the same. I feel since the "Overview" tab is enabled the other tabs are not what do you say enabled or its been displayed on screen but can't detect those. I hope i am making sense

Comment: are you able to click on it manually?can share the html code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ***JavaScriptExecutor*** for this task, WebDriver is not able to click on elements which are disabled or invisible. so try below code may be it will help you .

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
String xpath ="your xpath";
js.executeScript("document.querySelector("+xpath+").click()");
```